# Time out, Image send, Email track adding to bot framework composer

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I have developed a chatbot for IT Support team in our company, running on MS Teams using **Bot Framework Composer**. I have integrated it with Azure logic apps to send emails to IT Support team.
I want to know how to;

1. Get user's email address in MS Teams (We can get user's name using ${turn.activity.from.name} telemetry track event)
2. Set a timeout period
3. Send a Image to using HTTP request in JSON format (Then users can upload the screenshot of their issue)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can get the user's email address in MS teams by making fetching the roster or user profile or make use of get single member detail from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#nodejs-example).
2. Not sure if you want to restart a conversation or track the last time a message was received from a user, but you can refer to [Expire a conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-expire-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) documentation to get started with.
3. MS Teams makes use of webhooks to integrate with external apps and makes use of Standard HTTP message exchange [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook#outgoing-webhook-key-features) where responses appear in the same chain as the original request message and can include any bot framework message content, for example, rich text, images, cards, and emojis.

Comment: Actually I am new bot framework. Since I am using composer how do I actually add this to the bot framework composer.

Comment: could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload) to upload attachments to bot.